# c# Task.Run Syntax

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to run listOrders() on a separate thread and make it awaitable.
I have a method of this form, that compiles and works OK

```
private Task<ClearedOrdersReport> listOrdersAwaitable(int a, int b)
{
    Task<ClearedOrdersReport> t = Task.Run(() =>
       listOrders(a, b));
    return t;
}
```

I now want to add a second line to execute before the listOrders() call. I thought it would be trivial to change the single line lambda into a block style lambda, but I cannot figure out what the correct syntax is to get it to compile ? I am probably missing something obvious, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you wrapping listOrders in a Task.Run call?

Comment: Your question of "wanting to run listOrders() on a separate thread" doesn't make a lot of sense to me.   If you just make it async, and await it, it automatically decides where to run it with the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Also, by you just calling the function (and it not being async) -- it's already running as a task

Comment: I think more information about the bigger picture needs to be stated, because what you are asking is not making a lot of sense.

Comment: @IlanKeshet - No, it doesn't. [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: It is trivial to make this change. You should have posted the code that you tried so that we can better understand why you are asking so that we can give a better answer.

Comment: It's really important to differentiate between IO bound and compute bound.
When performing an IO bound task, there is no thread that's provisioned and blocked or running while the task is being performed at the OS/Device level. In compute bound, there is a thread that's executing the computation.

Comment: I found these responses rather confusing.  Just adding async and await to a function call does not make it run on another thread, hence why i have the Task.Run. Anyway code is fixed and working as intended now thanks, it was just silly oversight, I missed the return statement needed in a block lambda

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane - That's not entirely true. You can create a task that is compute bound and it runs synchronously on the calling thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity How is that, preemptively?

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane - this should do it: `async Task Compute() { int x = 0; while (true) { x++; } }`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [statement lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#statement-lambdas) and return the result of listOrders.

```
 private Task<ClearedOrdersReport> listOrdersAwaitable(int a, int b)
 {
        Task<ClearedOrdersReport> t = Task.Run(() => {
           //add your second line here. 
           return listOrders(a, b);
        });
        return t;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses. This solved it for me, my silly oversight was that in going from a single line lambda to a block lambda you dont have the implicit return statement. I forgot to add the return statement before listOrders().

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions about what you are trying to do with the async/await elements, but one to call two many things where there was one is to use a helper method:

```
listOrders(a, b));
```

can become

```
DoWork(a,b);
```

and then

```
ClearedOrdersReport DoWork(int a, int b)
{
 ...
 return listOrders(a, b); 
}
```